# How to upload file using axios post request

Tags: node.js, axios, http-post, form-data

I am trying to upload a file to url using axios post request. But i am getting 500 internal server error.
If the same request I tried from postman file gets uploaded with 200 status code. 
I am not sure what should be the content-Type here.
here is my code.

```
const axios = require('axios')
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require('request');
const formData = {
    file: fs.createReadStream('myfile.txt')
  }
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    };

axios.post('myurl',formData,config)
.then((res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`)
  console.log(res.data)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your frontend, when you click submit, do you call event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

```
const formData = {
    file: fs.createReadStream('myfile.txt')
}
```

It's a **plain javascript object**, not a ready-to-use formData. You just forget to transform it into a real FormData object. Just check for the document of `form-data` module.

Also it seems that when you post a real FormData, the "Content-type" header is unnecessary as `axios` will automaticly handle it for you.